# How to copy opentelemetry filelog receiver's file.log.name from attributes to resource?

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

How do I copy `file.log.name` from attributes to resource for filelog receiver?

Here is the receivers section of my config:

```
receivers:
  filelog:
    include: [/var/log/app/sample.log]
    start_at: beginning
    operators:
      - type: regex_parser
        regex: '^(?P<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}) \[?(?P<sev>[A-Z]*)\]? (?P<msg>.*)$'
        timestamp:
          parse_from: attributes.time
          layout: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L'
        severity:
          parse_from: attributes.sev

      - type: copy
        from: attributes.log.file.name
        to: resource.filename

    resource:
      deployment.env: "dev"
      service.name: "app"
      service.version: "1.0.0"
      host.name: ${env:HOSTNAME}
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
2023-12-07T10:30:48.829Z        error   helper/transformer.go:98        Failed to process entry {"kind": "receiver", "name": "filelog", "data_type": "logs", "operator_id": "copy", "operator_type": "copy", "error": "copy: from field does not exist in this entry: attributes.log.file.name", "action": "send", "entry": {"observed_timestamp":"2023-12-07T10:30:48.827639436Z","timestamp":"2023-12-07T10:00:40.123Z","body":"2023-12-07 10:00:40.123 [ERROR] This is a test error message 11111111111111","attributes":{"log.file.name":"sample.log","msg":"This is a test error message 11111111111111","sev":"ERROR","time":"2023-12-07 10:00:40.123"},"resource":{"deployment.env":"dev","host.name":"HOSTNAME","service.name":"app","service.version":"1.0.0"},"severity_text":"ERROR","severity":17,"scope_name":""}}
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/helper.(*TransformerOperator).HandleEntryError
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.88.0/operator/helper/transformer.go:98
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/helper.(*TransformerOperator).ProcessWith
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.88.0/operator/helper/transformer.go:90
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/transformer/copy.(*Transformer).Process
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.88.0/operator/transformer/copy/copy.go:73
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/helper.(*WriterOperator).Write
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.88.0/operator/helper/writer.go:53
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/helper.(*ParserOperator).ProcessWithCallback
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.88.0/operator/helper/parser.go:122
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/helper.(*ParserOperator).ProcessWith
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.88.0/operator/helper/parser.go:98
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/parser/regex.(*Parser).Process
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.88.0/operator/parser/regex/regex.go:99
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/helper.(*WriterOperator).Write
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.88.0/operator/helper/writer.go:53
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/input/file.(*Input).emit
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.88.0/operator/input/file/file.go:52
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/fileconsumer/internal/reader.(*Reader).ReadToEnd
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.88.0/fileconsumer/internal/reader/reader.go:106
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/fileconsumer.(*Manager).consume.func1
        github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.88.0/fileconsumer/file.go:156
```

If you look at the first line of error message, `attributes.log.file.name` does exist:

```
{
  "kind": "receiver",
  "name": "filelog",
  "data_type": "logs",
  "operator_id": "copy",
  "operator_type": "copy",
  "error": "copy: from field does not exist in this entry: attributes.log.file.name",
  "action": "send",
  "entry": {
    "observed_timestamp": "2023-12-07T10:30:48.827639436Z",
    "timestamp": "2023-12-07T10:00:40.123Z",
    "body": "2023-12-07 10:00:40.123 [ERROR] This is a test error message 11111111111111",
    "attributes": {
      "log.file.name": "sample.log",
      "msg": "This is a test error message 11111111111111",
      "sev": "ERROR",
      "time": "2023-12-07 10:00:40.123"
    },
    "resource": {
      "deployment.env": "dev",
      "host.name": "HOSTNAME",
      "service.name": "app",
      "service.version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "severity_text": "ERROR",
    "severity": 17,
    "scope_name": ""
  }
}
```

Copying another attribute works, for example this:

```
# This works...
      - type: copy
        from: attributes.sev
        to: resource.sev
```

### Context

- I cannot instrument the application with SDK because I have no access to the source code
- Application logs are written to disk, hence `filelog receiver` is used
- By default, `filelog receiver` adds `file.log.name` to `attributes` field. I can configure it to parse to `resource` field instead, but then I'll the same problem of moving other attributes from `resource` field back to `attributes` field
- filename cannot be added to and read from environment variables. Too many log files for too many systems on the same machine
- I have looked at `attributes processor` and `resource processor`, neither seems to allow access to the other's field

Also:

- `file.log.name` should ideally be parked under `resource` field because this is part of a larger architecture to consolidate distributed logs (not k8s, not nomad). In this case, `file name` is part of the source (resource), and `log entries` are values (attributes)
- Legacy system / architecture that is above my paygrade to change, otel is the first step to introduce centralized observability so we can (hopefully) inch towards a more functional distributed system

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Have confirmed that the square-brackets notation works for this use case, as stated in the [docs](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/pkg/stanza/docs/types/field.md):

```
      - type: copy
        from: attributes['log.file.name']
        to: resource['filename']
```

According to the docs, dot notation should behave the same. No idea why it doesn't work here. For those who encounter this issue in the future, you can check what the developers have done [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/issues/29696)